# Can Terraform resolve Azure interdependency issues, like renaming a resource?

Tags: azure, terraform, rename

Today I deployed an Azure environment using Terraform.  It's a simple collection of resources - a Resource Group, a VNET, a VM, a NIC, a Public IP, and a basic NSG.

After completing my deployment, I noticed I'd incorrectly named my Public IP and my NSG.

I modified my Terraform configuration, did a `terraform plan`, followed by a `terraform apply` to apply my changes, and it failed to do so with the following errors related to resources being in-use, and unable to be deleted as a result.

My question is -

1. Is it reasonable to expect Terraform to properly handle resolving dependencies and taking the necessary actions to enable a scenario like this?
2. Am I doing something wrong in my configuration?

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_network_interface.nic will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
        applied_dns_servers           = []
        dns_servers                   = []
        enable_accelerated_networking = false
        enable_ip_forwarding          = false
        id                            = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/app505-jmd-terraform-vm01-nic"
        location                      = "eastus2"
        mac_address                   = "00-0D-3A-7B-B9-EC"
        name                          = "app505-jmd-terraform-vm01-nic"
      ~ network_security_group_id     = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/app505-jmd-terraform" -> (known after apply)
        private_ip_address            = "10.0.1.4"
        private_ip_addresses          = [
            "10.0.1.4",
        ]
        resource_group_name           = "app505-jmd-terraform-rg"
        tags                          = {}
        virtual_machine_id            = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/app505-jmd-terraform-vm01"

      ~ ip_configuration {
            application_gateway_backend_address_pools_ids = []
            application_security_group_ids                = []
            load_balancer_backend_address_pools_ids       = []
            load_balancer_inbound_nat_rules_ids           = []
            name                                          = "myNicConfiguration"
            primary                                       = true
            private_ip_address                            = "10.0.1.4"
            private_ip_address_allocation                 = "dynamic"
            private_ip_address_version                    = "IPv4"
          ~ public_ip_address_id                          = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/app505-jmd-terraform" -> (known after apply)
            subnet_id                                     = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/app505-jmd-terraform-vnet/subnets/Internal"
        }
    }

  # azurerm_network_security_group.nsg must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
      ~ id                  = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/app505-jmd-terraform" -> (known after apply)
        location            = "eastus2"
      ~ name                = "app505-jmd-terraform" -> "app505-jmd-terraform-nsg" # forces replacement
        resource_group_name = "app505-jmd-terraform-rg"
        security_rule       = [
            {
                access                                     = "Allow"
                description                                = ""
                destination_address_prefix                 = "*"
                destination_address_prefixes               = []
                destination_application_security_group_ids = []
                destination_port_range                     = "22"
                destination_port_ranges                    = []
                direction                                  = "Inbound"
                name                                       = "SSH"
                priority                                   = 1001
                protocol                                   = "Tcp"
                source_address_prefix                      = "*"
                source_address_prefixes                    = []
                source_application_security_group_ids      = []
                source_port_range                          = "*"
                source_port_ranges                         = []
            },
        ]
      ~ tags                = {} -> (known after apply)
    }

  # azurerm_public_ip.pip must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
        allocation_method            = "Dynamic"
      + fqdn                         = (known after apply)
      ~ id                           = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/app505-jmd-terraform" -> (known after apply)
        idle_timeout_in_minutes      = 4
      ~ ip_address                   = "13.68.114.233" -> (known after apply)
        ip_version                   = "IPv4"
        location                     = "eastus2"
      ~ name                         = "app505-jmd-terraform" -> "app505-jmd-terraform-pip" # forces replacement
      ~ public_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic" -> (known after apply)
        resource_group_name          = "app505-jmd-terraform-rg"
        sku                          = "Basic"
      ~ tags                         = {} -> (known after apply)
      - zones                        = [] -> null
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 1 to change, 2 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

azurerm_public_ip.pip: Destroying... [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/app505-jmd-terraform]
azurerm_network_security_group.nsg: Destroying... [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/app505-jmd-terraform]

Error: Error deleting Network Security Group "app505-jmd-terraform" (Resource Group "app505-jmd-terraform-rg"): network.SecurityGroupsClient#Delete: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InUseNetworkSecurityGroupCannotBeDeleted" Message="Network security group /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/app505-jmd-terraform cannot be deleted because it is in use by the following resources: /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/app505-jmd-terraform-vm01-nic. In order to delete the Network security group, remove the association with the resource(s). To learn how to do this, see aka.ms/deletensg." Details=[]



Error: Error deleting Public IP "app505-jmd-terraform" (Resource Group "app505-jmd-terraform-rg"): network.PublicIPAddressesClient#Delete: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="PublicIPAddressCannotBeDeleted" Message="Public IP address /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/app505-jmd-terraform can not be deleted since it is still allocated to resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/app505-jmd-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/app505-jmd-terraform-vm01-nic/ipConfigurations/myNicConfiguration. In order to delete the public IP, disassociate/detach the Public IP address from the resource.  To learn how to do this, see aka.ms/deletepublicip." Details=[]



C:\Users\jdeli\OneDrive\Documents\Code\Terraform\terraform>
```

And finally, my configuration:

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    client_id       = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
    client_secret   = "cccccccccccccccc"
    tenant_id       = "dddddddddddddddd"
    skip_provider_registration = true
}

# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
    name     = "${var.prefix}-rg"
    location = var.location
}

# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "network" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}-vnet"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = var.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
    name                 = "Internal"
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.network.name
    address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
    name                         = "${var.prefix}-pip"
    location                     = var.location
    resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    allocation_method            = "Dynamic"
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
    name                = "${var.prefix}-nsg"
    location            = var.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

    security_rule {
        name                       = "SSH"
        priority                   = 1001
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "22"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
    name                      = "${var.prefix}-vm01-nic"
    location                  = var.location
    resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "myNicConfiguration"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
    }

}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "randomId" {
    keepers = {
        # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
        resource_group = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    }
    byte_length = 8
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "diagstorage" {
    name                        = "diag${random_id.randomId.hex}"
    resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    location                    = var.location
    account_tier                = "Standard"
    account_replication_type    = "LRS"
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {

    name                  = "${var.prefix}-"
    location              = var.location
    resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

    storage_os_disk {
        name              = "${var.prefix}-vm01-disk0"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
    }

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer     = "UbuntuServer"
        sku       = "16.04.0-LTS"
        version   = "latest"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "${var.prefix}-vm01"
        admin_username = "azureuser"
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = true
        ssh_keys {
            path     = "/home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
            key_data = "ssh-rsa xxxxxxxx"
        }
    }

    boot_diagnostics {
        enabled = "true"
        storage_uri = azurerm_storage_account.diagstorage.primary_blob_endpoint
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Deploy the above configuration
2. Rename the NSG and the Public IP address (the "name" properties)
3. Deploy again, and errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this would work for "top" level resources (so resource which do not have resource which depend on those). TF would delete and create those resources from scratch (you cannot really rename stuff in Azure).

For resources that have dependencies this would not work, because this means all the dependent resources have to be deleted first (or dependencies removed) and only then your resource can be renamed (so deleted\created with a new name) and then all the dependent resources have to be recreated\reconfigured

Comment: What's got me confused/ hopeful is the way Terraform seemed to "know" it would need to destroy and recreate the Public IP and the NSG (can't rename), and update the NIC accordingly.

This is of course necessary, but it misses a few dependencies like first disassociating the Public IP from the NIC, and NIC from the NSG.

It's like Terraform is half-aware of the dependencies and complexities of effecting this kind of change.  Is what I'm seeking to do beyond the scope of Terraform's intended uses?  Or perhaps should I open a bug with the Terraform team?  Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't know in more details, I avoid terraform like plague.

Comment: I'm curious why!  What's so bad about it, and what do you use instead?

Comment: hcl is the worst part of it, tbh. I use arm templates, ansible, pulumi